# Google Sheets - IF statement with INDEX arguments giving me #ERROR (Parse Error)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

To give some detail, I am using Google Forms + Google Sheets to make an easy database that collects all the bank information I put in (Income, savings, expenses, etc.) and I can keep track of details with easy sorting.

I'm stuck on a formula that I can't seem to figure out. Before I go in to specific details of my code I will give a small explanation. The cell I am trying to populate [with the formula] is supposed to take 2 pieces of information from the form response sheet (I will refer to it as '`rawdata`') and produce a value (number) from another cell in '`rawdata`'.

So in '`rawdata`' I have a column (`B`) that has a value of "`Expense`" or "`Income`" for a form response line. I have a column (`D`) in '`rawdata`' that has the value of "`Amount`" for the number submitted.

Cells in reference in '`rawdata`':

```
B9 = "Expense"

D9 = 67.37
```

Now, due to the original '`rawdata`' being a form response sheet it inserts new rows every response, so my attempt at just calling direction to the cell fails upon a new response submission because it increments on its own. So that being a solution is out of the question.

So, for every other cell I am using to display values from '`rawdata`' in an organized sheet I use `=INDEX()` to pull the value from that exact row and column, instead of the cell reference and it has worked so far.

`=INDEX(rawdata!$B:$B,ROW(9:9))` displays "`Expense`" from '`rawdata`' in `B9` as a result. So the rest of the cells are formulated this way and I have had no issues.

When I got to the amount, I used an `=IF()` formula to pull the value from the `D` column and to display it either as a negative or positive depending on what column `B` states.

`=IF(rawdata!B8="Expense", -rawdata!$D9, rawdata!$D9)` displays `-67.37` as a result.

But since I can't use this formula to fill empty cells for future use I have to find another way to do so. I figure;

```
=IF(=INDEX(rawdata!$B:$B,ROW(9:9)) = "Expense", =INDEX(-rawdata!$D:$D,ROW(9:9)), =INDEX(rawdata!$D:$D,ROW(9:9)))
```

is my solution to the problem, because to me it makes sense. But it fails and gives me a Parse Error.

So when I try to run the first `=INDEX()` with the values of `1` or `0` being the outcome of the `=IF()` it also fails, so I create a new column in the sorted table to pull the data of "`Expense`" or "`Income`" so I can reference that.

Cell in '`processeddata`':

```
E9 = "Expense"
```

`=IF(E9="Expense", 1, 0)` displays 1 as its result, so I figure this is the solution to my problem.

```
=IF(E9="Expense", =INDEX(-rawdata!$D:$D,ROW(9:9)), =INDEX(rawdata!$D:$D,ROW(9:9)))
```

displays `#ERROR` with the description Parse Error.

`=INDEX(-rawdata!$D:$D,ROW(9:9))` displays `-67.37`

`=INDEX(rawdata!$D:$D,ROW(9:9))` displays `67.37`

I'm at a loss for what to do now. I've exhausted myself with tons of searching on here and all over google, tried using things like `INDEX` and `MATCH`, `VLOOKUP`, etc but can't solve this to save my life. Does anyone here have a clue how I can solve this with a cell reference that won't increment when new rows are added in '`rawdata`'?

PS. I've also attempted using `=VALUE()` to try and convert the `=INDEX()` to a number but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula has some equal signs in it that are probably the issue.

***Instead of this:***

```
IF(=INDEX(rawdata!$B:$B,ROW(9:9)) = "Expense", =INDEX(-rawdata!$D:$D,ROW(9:9)), =INDEX(rawdata!$D:$D,ROW(9:9)))
```

try this:

```
IF(INDEX(rawdata!$B:$B,ROW(9:9)) = "Expense", INDEX(-rawdata!$D:$D,ROW(9:9)), INDEX(rawdata!$D:$D,ROW(9:9)))
```

Also, an [array formula](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/array-formula-intro/) is a great tool for Form data calculations. In [this file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rOMIRyCslbdmggzc2ScMVTC4FVSnZt8bUhSJmajiOUk/edit?resourcekey=null#gid=1473907674) you can see a formula in `Column F` that does a calculation in each row of the responses sheet from [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdvLuJnEO6Hy7v0-WSU_alz_Pg2bKn_IXWliIoYVU2hteLm1w/viewform), it will continue to update as new entries are made. Feel free to enter submit some form responses.

Comment: Thank you so damn much. I was pulling my hair out last night trying to get this to work. You've saved me so many days off my life because of this solution. Thank you again!

Edit: I had to leave the IF with an = on it, the INDEX formulas though I removed them.

Comment: @StonedFox checkout the updated answer with an array example. Such a formula is absolutely a must-have with using forms. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula has superfluous equals signs (`=`). Try **Insert > Column** and this formula in row 8 of the new column:

`=arrayformula( if(rawdata!B8:B = "Expense", -rawdata!D8:D, rawdata!D8:D) )`

Comment: I think I beat you by a couple seconds. Good answer. Upvoting.